# Understanding why I'm getting a recursion error inside of a get method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, properties

I'm currently learning about properties and ran into a bit of a problem. When I return my property in the `get` method, I receive a recursion error.

Is this because whenever I return the property it activates the get method, which returns the property, which activates the get method, etc?

Here's my code:

```
using UnityEngine;

struct Enemy
{
    public int Bonus;
    private int gold; 

    public int Gold
    {
        get
        {
            return Gold + Bonus;  
        }                       
        set                 
        {
            gold = value; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `return Gold + Bonus;` should be `return gold + Bonus;`.

Comment: Why are you using a struct?  You should use a class, if you want a value to be associated to modify value or be automatically set by other classes do { get; set; } if you want the class to have a new value at construction you need those values in advance or set as fields initially.  You should also follow C# naming conventions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Cause-

You are using the `Gold` property itself in its getter which recursively calls its getter again and again.

> Solution-

Use the variable instead-

```
public int Gold
{
    get
    {
        return gold + Bonus;  
    }    
    set                
    {
        gold = value; 
    }
}
```

Comment: So would I be correct in my understanding? When you return the property you activate the get method and the loop continues?

Comment: Yes, Properties are meant to return or set the value of the private variables associated with them.

Comment: Differentiating commonly-scoped variables using casing is generally considered bad practice.  Personally, I prefix any field that is shadowing a property with an underscore.  In your case, I would use `private int _Gold;  public int Gold {get{} set{}}`

Answer (score 3):

Because you are calling `Gold` endlessly

```
public int Gold // here
{
    get
    {
        return Gold + Bonus; // here
```

I.e

```
Give me Gold 

Gold  + Bonus

oh give me Gold

Gold  + Bonus

etc.
```

before it can add bonus, it calls Gold again

I'll let you figure out how to fix it, as it should be obvious.